# Check Missing Time Interval In SQL in Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement as below and I wish to check the data in time interval in minutes where the `D.DatalogValue` didn't have any value and it won't show as Null or zero value either. The sample as below output result will be show 2016-06-01 00:32:29 as missing createdDate.

```
SELECT 
    A.DefID, A.ObjID, 
    C.ObjName, C.Dev_ID,
    A.Pro_ID, A.ArrayIndex,
    A.DefType, A.TObjID, A.DimeId, A.DefId,
    D.DatalogValue, D.PanelDt, D.CreatedDate
FROM 
    Table A, Table C, Table D
WHERE 
    A.ObjID = C.ObjID
    AND C.ObjID = '2627'
    AND A.DefID = D.DefID
    AND D.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-02'
ORDER BY 
    C.ObID,C.ObjName;
```

Sample data:

```
Create Date             DatalogValue
-------------------------------------
2016-06-01 00:29:29     0.01
2016-06-01 00:30:29     0.02
2016-06-01 00:31:29     0.03

2016-06-01 00:33:29     0.04
```

By using the solution provided i have come out a SQL statement but it still no able to show the result i want. I not sure which part i doing wrong my code as below:

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-07-01';
 DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-07-31';

WITH Check_Dates AS (
SELECT @StartDate [Date] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, [Date]) FROM Check_Dates
WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
)

SELECT 
FORMAT(d.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') [Created Date]

FROM Check_Dates d
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 
Format(D.CreatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')as created_dt

FROM TABLE A
,TABLE C
,TABLE D
WHERE A.ObjID=C.ObjID
AND C.ObjID IN('3915')
AND A.DefID=D.DefID
AND D.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-01'
)

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Either you need an `outer join` or maybe a `times` table with an `outer join` -- difficult to say without sample data and expected results (and possibly table structures).

Comment: @sgeddes hi i reedit my post with sample data because the problem i facing was it didn't insert zero or null it will direct skip it and i need to show which minutes it didn't show up.

Comment: Create a table containing all minutes within a certain interval. Outer join against that on the fully qualified minutes. Take only results that have a reference date but no data.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @sgeddes that mean my table need a fields and content 1440 records. lol~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use a CTE to create a list of `DATETIME`s then `LEFT JOIN` these onto your original query. You can also create a pair of tables instead (as mentioned in the comments) - google DimDate and/or DimTime.

Something like (untested):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-06-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-06-02';

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate [Date] 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 1, [Date]) FROM Dates
    WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
)
SELECT 
 d.Date [Created Date]
 ,COALESCE(Qry.DatalogValue, 0) DatalogValue
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN (
   Your query goes here
) Qry
ON d.Date = Qry.CreatedDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Hi les thank you for ur suggestion i get a syntax error at line 9. After i fix it will let u know it working or not

Comment: just check with you what should i put for the D.DatalogValue? Mind to share

Comment: Sorry, typo - it's just the value you're selecting in your subquery, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems very risky to me. Are you sure seconds should be compared? I would truncate to minutes. I suggest more robust solution:

```
WITH Dates AS
( --Your dates and values
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('2016-06-01 00:29:29', 0.01),
    ('2016-06-01 00:30:29', 0.02),
    ('2016-06-01 00:31:29', 0.03),
    ('2016-06-01 00:33:29', 0.04)--,('2016-06-01 01:00:28', 0.05)
    ) T(CreateDate, CatalogValues)
), Minute10 AS --Generate numbers from 0-999999
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0)) T1(Value)
), Minute1000 AS
(
    SELECT M1.Value FROM Minute10 M1 CROSS JOIN Minute10 M2 CROSS JOIN Minute10
), Minute1000000 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1 Value
    FROM Minute1000
    CROSS JOIN Minute1000 M2
), RangeValues AS --for simplicity, min and max values from dates
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MIN(CreateDate)), 0) MinDate,
           DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, MAX(CreateDate)), 0) MaxDate
    FROM Dates
)
SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(MINUTE, (SELECT MinDate FROM RangeValues), (SELECT MaxDate FROM RangeValues)))
DATEADD(MINUTE,Value,MinDate) ExpectedDate, CreateDate, CatalogValues
FROM Minute1000000
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MinDate FROM RangeValues) T
LEFT JOIN Dates ON DATEADD(MINUTE,Value,MinDate)=DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CreateDate), 0)
```

Note that all dates are truncated to minutes. You can simplyfy query by removing number generation part (numbers can be placed in utility table, 1440 values if that's all you need). Min and Max can be precalculated.

This results in following output (can handle ranges minDate+999999 minutes, can be simply extended):

```
ExprectedDate             CreateDate            CatalogValues
2016-06-01 00:29:00.000   2016-06-01 00:29:29   0.01
2016-06-01 00:30:00.000   2016-06-01 00:30:29   0.02
2016-06-01 00:31:00.000   2016-06-01 00:31:29   0.03
2016-06-01 00:32:00.000   NULL                  NULL
2016-06-01 00:33:00.000   2016-06-01 00:33:29   0.04
```

---

**Explanation:**

Dates is just source table. Tables `Minute10`..`Minute1000000` are to generate numbers from 0 to 999999 (10 cross joined 10 = 100, 100 cross joined x3 = 100^3 = 1000000. Records from last table are numbered to get sequential values. Don't worry, TOP prevents from evaluating all 1000000 values. `RangeValues` contains MAX and MIN dates, for simplicity.

**Algorithm:**

Since you need records from MIN date to MAX date every minute, you evaluate `TOP DATETIFF(MINUTE,MIN,MAX)+1` records (+1 to avoid Fencepost error). All required tables are joined (`CROSS APLLY` adds MIN column to every record), Expected date is calculated as MIN date + sequential value in minutes. Last join, LEFT one, matches date generated for every minute with source table. If there is match, record is appended (joined). If there is no match, NULL is appended. Note `DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @someDate), 0)' truncates seconds from date.

Comment: Hi pawel your solution is a bit complicated foe me would you like to explain in more details?